# Grease Pencil - Keyframes disappear in Object Mode?

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, object-mode

I'm learning 2D animation in Blender. Keyframing works normal in all modes except *Object Mode*. Every time, when I switch back to *Object Mode*, and click any blank place, all keyframes disappear but the animation is still moving.

[image]

**Q:** Why does my keyframes disappear in *Object Mode*?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, by default you can only see keyframes of the selected objects. That means that if I draw the line and click outside of that line in object mode, keyframes will disappear because you have no object selected.
[image]
[image]

Right here at the left, you see what is selected:
[image]

With this setting, you can only see what you have selected (orange outline) This may be helpful to see what you are working with. However, if you want all the keyframes to be visible, you can uncheck this option:

[image]

With this option unchecked, you will always see all the keyframes of all the objects in your animation... If you will want to separate keyframes of only one object again, just check this option again.